# How to print out a hash that is named like a regular variable

Tags: perl

I've been thrust into supporting a perl cgi program, and I have very little functional perl experience.

There is a method that takes $args and I want to see what the $args are.

Here's how I tried first:

```
print( "=== DEBUG 2 === Creating session with the following args: ", $args, "\n" );
```

Which prints:

```
=== DEBUG 2 === Creating session with the following args: HASH(0x2b462cc7c880)
```

So it's a hash, ah, well.  A little googling and I try this:

```
my $counter = 1;
print( "=== DEBUG === Creating session with the following args: \n" );
foreach (keys $args) {
    print "$_ : $args{$_}\n";
}
```

This causes the entire program to crash with no helpful error message.  I guess that $args cannot be used with keys.

How can I dump the contents of $args to print ?

Note:  Trying to use Data Dumper also causes the entire program to crash with no error message.

Comment: how are you calling data dumper? Since that is a reference to a hash you would call it `Dumper($args)`.

Comment: Are you testing your CGI on the command line? If so, you should get *some* kind of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$args` is not a hash, it's a hash *reference*. You need to dereference it first to access the underlying hash.

```
foreach (keys %$args) {
    # You could use this:
    #   print "$_: ${$args}{$_}\n";
    # but the -> operator is a little more readable.
    print "$_: $args->{$_}\n";
}
```

The `each` operator lets you iterate over a hash while providing a name for each key and value:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %$args) {
    print "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
foreach (keys %{$args}) {
    print "$_ : ".$args->{$_}."\n";
}
```

Probably $args is not a hash, but a reference to a hash.

Answer (score 1):

$args seems to be a hash reference.

To print the entire hash:

```
print %$args;
```

To print it key by key:

```
print "$_ $args->{$_}\n" foreach (keys %$args);
```